# why we use this getWindow().close All Panels() in android?

Tags: android, homescreen

here i want to know about this code

i am implementing a new customize home screen in android
so i used this code. so i want to know why we used here `getWindow().closeAllPanels();` this thing. close default home screen of android?

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        // Close the menu
        if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            getWindow().closeAllPanels();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment explains why :) If you are already on the home screen with the menu open and the user presses the menu key, this code closes the menu. Pressing home is used to reset to a known state (launcher's middle screen, no open menu.)

Comment: means using this code i cant open the menu from my customize home screen?